# For loops-accumulation

Tags: python, for-loop

This is from one of the question for my class, learning to use Forloops-accum-if.  And I'm kind of stuck on the question.

I have to write a code which would use accumulation.

This is what I have so far.

```
def sequenceDigitsAndStars (dig):
    st = "*"
    for i in range(len(dig)):
        if(st[i].isdigit()):
            dig = dig + st[i]
    return st
```

I'm getting 'Memory Error' with this code.

The question says that, if I type in a number (i.e. `5`) for the value `dig`, it should return `0*1*2*3*4*5*`. I'm having trouble on it, I don't know how I can make it so that it would put the number, starting from the `0`, alternating with star (`0*`). (how can I make it alternate the pattern `0*`, when I use a number as input value?)

Comment: What would you expect `len(5)` to be?

Comment: st[i] is the i-th element in st

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should fix your problem.

```
def sequenceDigitsAndStars (dig):
    st = ""
    for i in range(dig + 1):
        st += str(i) + '*'
    return st
```

Comment: The example wants to return additional

Comment: Thank you, this code work perfectly. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
def sequenceDigitsAndStars (dig):
    return '*'.join(map(str, range(dig))
```

This will get the range of 0-dig, convert it to an array of strings and then combine the elements with  `*`s

If you want a trailing `*`, you can do

```
def sequenceDigitsAndStars (dig):
    return '*'.join(map(str, range(dig)) + '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this?

```
print "*".join(str(i) for i in xrange(dig+1))
```

Since it's homework you can use this:

```
def sequenceDigitsAndStars (dig):
    string = ""
    for i in range(dig):
        string += str(i)+"*"
    string += str(i+1)
    return string
```

which has a couple of performance issues.

Comment: @Basic and so? I cannot see the comment anymore. I cannot understand.